# Angular 6 - access array in array from a ReactiveForm

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following form

```
    this.questionForm = this.fb.group({
      title: [],
      questions: this.fb.array(
        [
          this.fb.group({
            question: [],
            answers: this.fb.array([this.fb.group({answer: ''})])
          })
        ]
      )
    });
  }
```

I have no problems with looping trough the questions. However I am not entirely sure how I can access the answers array from my template.

this is what i currently have in my template

```
<div formArrayName="questions">
  <div class="form-row" *ngFor="let question of questions.controls; let questionIndex=index" [formGroupName]="questionIndex">
    <button (click)="test(1)"></button>
    <div class="col">
      <textarea formControlName="question" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your question here" rows="6"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <!-- Here I want to loop trough the questions but i am not sure how-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So what should I do to loop through the answers?

Comment: `{{ question.value }}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just looping the `answers` array for each question in the same manner as you are iterating your questions. In contrary to the answer provided by Husein, I would not call a function in the iteration, since it will be called on each change detection, which is **often** especially when you can have a lot of bindings. So what I would do in template is (shortened code)...

```
<form [formGroup]="questionForm">
  <div formArrayName="questions">
    <div *ngFor="let quest of questionForm.get('questions').controls; let questionIndex=index" [formGroupName]="questionIndex">
      <textarea formControlName="question"></textarea>
      <div formArrayName="answers">
        <div *ngFor="let answ of quest.get('answers').controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
          <input formControlName="answer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

DEMO: **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y3x7uz?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Great, glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a FormArray within FormArray on the screen. It should be something like this:

```
<div formArrayName="questions">
    <div class="form-row" *ngFor="let question of questions.controls; let questionIndex=index" [formGroupName]="questionIndex">
        <button (click)="test(1)"></button>
        <div class="col">
            <textarea formControlName="question" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your question here" rows="6"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col" formArrayName="answers">
            <div class="form-row" *ngFor="let answer of getAnswers(question).controls; let j=index" [formGroupName]="j">
                <input type="text" formControlName="answer" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And `getAnswers` method could look something like:

```
getAnswers(question): FormArray {
    const answers = question.get('answers') as FormArray;

    return answers;
}
```

I have not tested this code, but this is how you would usually do it.